# Adding ImageIcon to JButton making it dissapear

Tags: java

```
BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("res//Login Button.png"));
loginButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
```

I've been using the above code to try and add an Image to a JButton, but the button isn't showing up on the frame, and I keep getting NullPointerException. Here's the actual code to create the button:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setFont(new Font("Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    loginButton.setBounds(212, 252, 211, 55);
    try {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/LoginButton.png"));
        loginButton = new JButton("", image);
        panel.add(loginButton);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    panel.add(loginButton);
```

Comment: post the error stacktrace  ..does image exist ?

Comment: is it `LoginButton.png` or `Login Button.png`? There's an inconsistency between your example at the top and the actual at the bottom.

Comment: @leigero it's LoginButton.png

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two instances of your JButton / overwriting Text of the First to replace the second. Change your code to this:

```
JButton loginButton = null;

try {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/LoginButton.png"));
    loginButton = new JButton("", image);
    panel.add(loginButton);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }


if (!loginButton)
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");

loginButton.setFont(new Font("Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", Font.PLAIN, 20));
loginButton.setBounds(212, 252, 211, 55);

panel.add(loginButton);
```

Comment: You can't call loginButton.setFont() right after setting loginButton = null !

Comment: nice catch @FredK! Modified to show correct solution.

Comment: The OP didn't put any text when the image is added, so just setFont only if there will be text. Placing the one with text in the catch-clause eliminates the need for the later if-test.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton loginButton = null;   
try {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/LoginButton.png"));
        loginButton = new JButton("", image);
        panel.add(loginButton);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            loginButton = new LoginButton("Login")(;
            loginButton.setFont(new Font("Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        }
    panel.add(loginButton);
```

Calling loginButton.setBounds() probably has no effect - let the layout manager place the button.